# Javascript console logged DATE type POSTGRESQL reduced 1 day

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express

I have a database with date as the Id and im going to select the date/id of the last 5 days from my postgresql database to browser using command bellow and send it to the client side using `res.send` on node/express

```
SELECT * FROM ratings ORDER BY rating_id DESC LIMIT 5
```

[image]

but if i console log it, it always less 1 day behind, 2021-04-02 even not in the database

[image]

i have done parsed it from the client side, but what i got is only the last 4 days, 2021-04-03 is missing

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is because your data field has a timezone component. So my question is: do you need store the timezone component in your dates?
If yes. So when you format your time you need take it in consideration. The browser automatically go to give you the date in the browser time zone, for that may be you can get a day more or less.
If no, you can format the date without take the timezone component.

PD: you should store your date values as UTC date in your DB always.